# Can I identify all iTunes purchases bought with a particular ID Account?

Tags: mac, apple-id, password

Having restored back-up from iCloud I am being repeatedly asked for the password for a work-related email address. I was made redundant from that company about 10 years ago and cannot retrieve that password.
I'm willing to bite the bullet and erase all the relevant tracks from iTunes in an attempt to solve this problem.
My question is, can I identify them all in one go using Purchase History (or whatever) without the password for that particular account, or will I have to trawl through the tracks/albums individually?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by opening Terminal (/Applications/Utilities/) and entering the following command:

```
grep -rl username@example.com ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Music
```

…where `username@example.com` is the email of the account you purchased the iTunes content with. This will look for references to that name in all of the downloaded files in your iTunes directory. I don't buy a lot of music through the ITMS but this seems to identify the ones that I purchased through a specific account.

There is also this [Track Down Purchases](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=trackdownpurchases) application. I have not tried it, but it looks like it would also do what you want.

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any way of identifying purchases at the local system level. The only manner of which I'm aware is to log into an iTunes account at the Store and examine the purchases made from within the account. At that point, it's a matter of divide and conquer.